# how can I run the Thales "NC" diagnostic host command from linux / cygwin console

Tags: linux, cygwin, hsm

I would like to run the Thales NC (Perform Diagnostics) host command directly from a linux / cygwin console.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have **xxd** and **nc** (netcat) installed, you can peform the following:

```
$ echo '0006303030304e43' | xxd -r -p | nc localhost 9998
!0000ND007B44AC1DDEE2A94B0007-E000
```

The command **0006303030304e43** is broken down as follows:

- 0006 = the command length in hex (i.e. length of **0000NC**)
- 30303030 = the 4 byte header **0000** in hex
- 4e43 = the 2 byte command **NC** in hex

**!0000ND007B44AC1DDEE2A94B0007-E000** - this is the response from the HSM.

---

If you don't have **xxd**, you can use **Perl**:

```
echo '0006303030304e43' | perl -e 'print pack "H*", <STDIN>' | nc localhost 9998
```

---

UPDATE 1: An even simpler solution:

```
echo -ne '\x00\x06\x30\x30\x30\x30\x4e\x43' | nc localhost 9998
```

---

UPDATE 2: A pure perl solution:

```
perl -e 'use IO::Socket::INET; 
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(PeerAddr=>"localhost:9998") or die; 
$sock->send(pack "H*","0006303030304e43"); 
$sock->recv($data, 1024); print $data;'
```

(just copy and paste into your bash prompt)